# RMI Application

Tags: java, deployment, rmi

I am working on a development of a paperless system for leaves application and for asking queries and for scheduling meetings.  It will have 3 categories of users namely Admin side, staffs and students. I am using eclipse to write an RMI application. It comprises of :

- Admin - Consist of the screens the admin will be using
- Admin_Main - This is the Main Server which bind the interfaces in the registry
- Common - Common screens used by both admin, staff and student side
- Implementation - The development of the methods defined in the Interfaces
- Interfaces - The methods that will be used by admin, staff and student are defined here
- Staff - The screens used by the staffs
- Student - the screen used by the student

Also in a few interfaces in my RMI application, i am using org.eclipse.swt to display calendar, to allow users to input date just by choosing on the calendar. When I tried to run it in command prompt, but it is not recognizing the  `org.eclipse.swt` package.

So my question is how can i deploy my whole RMI application to make it run without eclipse, and i want to deploy it separately, that is staff, admin and student separately to be able to make it work on a real network. If i run these on eclipse using an RMI plugin, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a client/server application, where the two share a common interface.

Eclipse is hiding some of those deployment details from you, but you'll have to sort them out to deploy without it.

You have to have client and server JARs, with all their separate dependencies available, plus a common JAR for the classes they share.

You have to have an RMI container that's listening for RMI requests from clients on a port of your choosing.

Have you written your server to use one thread per request or non-blocking IO?  You should know if there will be lots of clients simultaneously accessing your server.

Comment: Hi.. Yes many clients will be accessing the server simultaneously. But i don't know how to make the jars..

Comment: I have been able to generate the jar. I have installed a Fat-Jar Plugin on Eclipse. I have done only for admin part so far (Just trying fro now). I've tried to export the all the folders to be used by the admin side in one jar..(Admin, Admin_Main, Interface, Common, Implementation). My main class consist of codes to bind the methods in the registry and a code to show the login screen for the admin. When i deployed all these, it showed a java icon, but when i try to run it, it shows an empty screen, I don't know may be it is not recognizing the codes to bind the methods in the registry?

Comment: No, go back to your other comment: I don't know how to make the JARs.  You are having much more fundamental problems.  I would recommend abandoning Eclipse - it's only getting in the way.  Learn how to use the jar.exe tool - it's bundled in with your javac.exe and java.exe in the JDK /bin folder.  Think about what goes into each of the client, server, and common JARs and use jar.exe to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploying your RMI application on Apache Tomcat with the RMI plugin?

Im not too good with RMI, but did a unit on it last year at university, and to deploy it, we used Apache Tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/)